# Logarithmic differentiation and negative valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation

I have seen the following proof for the power rule:

$$
\begin{align*}
y &= x^n\\
\ln(y) &= n\ln(x)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(y) &= \frac{d}{dx}(n\ln(x))\\
\frac{y'}{y} &= \frac{n}{x}\\
y' &= nx^{n-1}
\end{align*}
$$

However, what I don't understand is how is this proof valid if $y$ may be negative and then $\ln(y)$ would not be defined. Even if $y'$ is indeed $nx^{n-1}$, isn't this proof a wrong way to achieve the right answer?

Comment: One: you can allow complex numbers.  Two: If you do not want to allow complex numbers, then you have to proceed more carefully.  The "logarithmic derivative" of $f(x)$ is $f'(x)/f(x)$ as long as $f(x)$ is nonzero.  No assumption on the sign of $f(x)$.  No mention of logarithms.

Comment: Yes, if $y $ is negative then you can't take the log. Care is needed also with the righthandside. For example $y=\log {(-x)^2} $ is defined and is equal to $y=\log {(x)^2}$ , so you need to take care when working with these quantities.

Comment: $\ln|y|=n \ln|x|$, etc.

Comment: Take absolute value before taking logarithm, then apply the result in the addendum [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4275258/21813).