# Isn't my book doing this math about differentiation wrongly?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Problem:**

Differentiate with respect to $x$: $\ln\left(e^x\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$

**My attempt:**

Let,

$$y=\ln\left(e^x\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$

Both $e^x$ and $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ are positive: $e^x$ can never be negative, and you can take the square root of only positive numbers, so $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ is positive as well. So, we can apply logarithm properties:

$$=\ln e^x+\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$=x+\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$

Now,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{3}{2}.\frac{x+1}{x-1}.\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$

$$=1+\frac{3}{2}.\frac{x+1}{x-1}.\frac{x+1-x+1}{(x+1)^2}$$

$$=1+\frac{3}{2}.\frac{x+1}{x-1}.\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$$

We can cancel $(x+1)$ and $(x+1)$ in the numerator and denominator because the graph doesn't change.

$$=1+\frac{3}{x^2-1}$$

$$=\frac{x^2+2}{x^2-1}$$

**My book's attempt:**

Let,

$$y=\ln\left(e^x\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$$

$$=\ln e^x+\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$=x+\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$

$$=x+\frac{3}{2}\left(\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+1)\right)\tag{1}$$

$$...$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+2}{x^2-1}$$

**Question:**

1. In my book's attempt, is line $(1)$ valid? I think my book's assumption in $(1)$ that $(x-1)$ and  $(x+1)$ must be positive is unfounded. I deduced that $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ is positive; $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ can be positive even when both $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ is negative. So, is line $(1)$ of my book valid?

Comment: The book seems to be assuming $x > 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **My book's attempt:**
>
> $$y=x+\frac{3}{2}\ln(\frac{x-1}{x+1})$$
> $$=x+\frac{3}{2}(\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+1))\tag{1}\\\ldots$$
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+2}{x^2-1}$$
>
> is line $(1)$ valid? I think my book's assumption that $(x-1)$ & $(x+1)$ must be positive is unfounded. $\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ can be positive even when both $(x-1)$ & $(x+1)$ are negative.

The author is hand-waving; pretending that $x-1$ and $x+1$ are nonnegative doesn't affect the result.

To be rigorous: on our domain of interest, $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x+\frac32\ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)\\ =\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x+\frac32\ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|\right)\\ =\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x+\frac32\Big(\ln \left|{x-1}\right|-\ln\left|{x+1}\right| \Big)\right),$$ noting that $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln|f(x)|=\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)}.$$

This hand-wavy issue of implicit modulus signs when there are logarithmic functions, is also common when solving differential equations: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3807340/21813) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3804321/21813).

And here is a related answer: [How is taking $\ln$ on both sides justified?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4498616/21813)

---

**Addendum**

For negative $f(x),$ $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln\left|f(x)\right|\\=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln\left(-f(x)\right)\\=\frac{-f'(x)}{-f(x)}\\=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)};$$ for positive $f(x),$ again $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\ln\left|f(x)\right|=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.$$

Comment: I think your second line should be

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln e^x+\frac{3}{2}\ln(|\frac{x-1}{x+1}|)]$$

You didn't add the modulus sign

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic No, it’s correct and I intentionally  displayed that step for clarity: as you’ve ownself pointed out in your Question, the fraction in parentheses _is_ positive (though this was NOT the relevant reasoning for your 2nd line there). *This is why* adding the modulus symbol in the next line is valid.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic P.S. I hope you continue asking these thoughtful questions, on issues that tend to be glossed over in textbooks. I think MSE is a great forum / knowledge base for such Q&A’s.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic I second ryang's suggestion.  Please do continue to ask such thoughtful questions.  +1!  =)

Answer (score 9):

Giving a restriction of the domain is an issue of this problem, because that quantity is defined only for $x<-1\lor x>1$. In my opinion, if this were part of a "gauntlet of exercises" in some textbook, then an indication of the domain should be specified, if the purpose of the exercise lies elsewhere: at the very least, to avoid wasting time.
For instance, I think that such a thing would be very important in the chapters about **anti**derivatives.

You're right: based on the information you've given, $\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+1)$ is unwarranted, because the natural way to address the problem would be for all $x$ such that $x<-1\lor x>1$. The book could have solved the issue by saying that $\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\ln\lvert x-1\rvert-\ln\lvert x+1\rvert$ (which is true in the natural domain) and then using $\frac{d}{dt}\ln\lvert t\rvert=\frac1t$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! My way of doing the math is correct though, right? How does my book reach the correct answer if its method was incorrect?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Sometimes a proof wrong, but the final result is true. In point of fact, it's what mathematicians lowkey hope for when we'll have AI-s review the literature of the last 50 years.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. My way of doing the math was correct, right?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Yes, it's fine.

Comment: tbh you have pointed out a great thing. I missed out this argument when I solved this problem. Thanks mate