# Why is the antiderivative of $\dfrac{1}{x}=\ln(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is equal to $\dfrac{1}{x}$. What I don't get is why the antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\ln(|x|)$ instead of $\ln(x)$. Why is the absolute value sign necessary? I would like a simple explanation as I am new to calculus. Thanks!

Comment: Go to the addendum of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4275258/21813). Let's continue from the work there by letting $f(x)=x$ then integrating the equation in each case. Then, we have that $\int\frac1x\,\mathrm dx$ equals $\ln|x|+C_1$for negative $x,$ and equals $\ln|x|+C_2$for positive $x.$ (Notice that this integral exists if and only if the domain of integration is a subset of $(-\infty,0)$ or a subset of $(0,\infty).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln (x)$ is only defined on $(0,\infty)$, so you need to ensure it's accounted for as an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$, since $\frac{1}{x}$ is defined over all values except $0$.

For $\frac{d}{dx} \ln (x)$ we are implicitly restricting the domain to $(0, \infty)$.